# Is the set of non finitely describable real numbers closed under addition and squaring?

Tags: computer-science

Is the set of non finitely describable real numbers closed under addition and squaring?  If so, can someone give a proof?  Thanks.

Comment: non finitely describable real numbers = irrational?  $\sqrt{2}^2 = 2$ ?

Comment: This has a good picture that explains it http://i.imgur.com/ySI0Lu1.png

Comment: What precisely do you mean by "finitely describable"?

Comment: I took it to mean "can be described for a fixed language by a finite sentence".

Comment: @V-X, ChrisEagle: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definable_real_number

Comment: @V-X $\sqrt 2$ is finitely describable: the positive real number whose square is $2$.

Answer (score 2):

if $x$ is not finitely describable, then $-x$ is not finitely describable either. But $0=x+(-x)$ is finitely describable so no closure under addition.

Now if $x^2$ is finitely describable, then $x$ is finitely describable (it's described as "the square root (either positive or negative) of the number described by the description of $x$"). So, you do have closure under squaring.

Comment: Isn't your last paragraph an argument for closure under squaring?

Comment: @RossMillikan oooops auto-pilot crashing. Thanks. I'm correcting it.

Answer (score 1):

If $x$ is non-describable, so is $-x$. So certainly we do not have closure under addition.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the answer is "no," though I might have the wrong definition of "finitely describable."

Take any non-finitely-describable number $N$ and consider the number $K = 1 - N$.  This number cannot be finitely describable, since if it were, we could describe $N$ as $1 - K = 1 - (1 - N) = N$.  However, $N + K = N + (1 - N) = 1$, which is finitely describable.  Thus the non-finitely-describable numbers are not closed under addition.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Hum... if by non-finitely-describable you mean "can't construct a finite description (as e.g. a Turing machine)", they aren't closed with respect to addition: $a + b = 2$ if $a$ is one of yours, $b$ is too (if it wasn't, $a$ could be described). But 2 clearly isn't.

Squares I have no clue.